# Custom Post type collection

Tags: custom-post-types

If you've set up custom types and given them a custom slug through `register_post_type`

```
'rewrite'  => array(
    'slug' => "shoes"
)
```

Can you assign a template for `/shoes/`? At the moment all custom types are just nested inside of a url path that's dead if you navigate to it without the specific item at the end

`/shoes/specific_shoe` -> custom post

`/shoes/` -> index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `has_archive` set to `true` in you `register_post_type` function? If so, you can use `archive-shoes.php` as your archive template.

For more information about registering custom post types, please check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

**EDIT**

To load a custom archive template (without having to use the default WP template naming conventions), you can use the `archive_template` hook to set your own.

```
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'my_shoes_archive_template' );
function my_shoes_archive_template($archive_template) {
     global $post;
     if ( is_post_type_archive ('shoes') ) {
          $archive_template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/my-file-name.php';
     }
     return $archive_template;
}
```

Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/ for more information on this.

Comment: Oh yeah, has_archive did the trick! Can you register the archive template programmatically and not through a naming convention somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use a hook to set your own template. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you that solves all of my problems :)

Comment: You are very welcome :)